# Best way to return message back to form from class instance?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, class, message-queue

I wondered if anyone could help me out...

Im working with an MQ API, specifically the "Listening" part, whereby I've connected to a Queue and I'm waiting to pick up messages.

Im using a Winforms app, C# .NET 3.5 to work with this API.

To use the API I must create an instance like so:

```
private void btnConnect(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageQueue myMQ = new MessageQueue();
    myMQ.Connect(...);
    //Register handler
        myMQ.MsgTrigger += new EventHandler(passMessage);
}

public void passMessage(object s, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s.ToString()); //Not sure if this is a good way to pass back a value
}
```

Which implements the class (That in turn inherits from MessageListener):

```
namespace MQListener
{
    class MessageQueue : MQ.MessageListener
    {
        public event EventHandler MsgTrigger;

        public virtual void onMessage(MQ.Message Message)
        {
            MQ.TextMessage txtMessage = (MQ.TextMessage)Message;
            String MsgBody = txtMessage.getMessage();
            Console.WriteLine(MsgBody);

            object objMsg = (object)MsgBody;

            var _Trigger = MsgTrigger;

                if(_Trigger != null)
                   _Trigger(objMsg, null);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, inheriting from MQ.MessageListener allows me to override the onMessage() method, which in turn is triggered everytime a message is received on that queue.

As that happens silently in the background I'm unsure whats the best method to return the message text back to the form where the class instance was created opposed to just outputting the MsgBody to the console. I dont ever call onMessage(), its triggered, so I cant retrun a value back to the form.

***Update***

I have added in an eventhandler to pass the received message back to the user form where the method PassMessage() writes the message out to the console.

Strangely when I manually send a message to onMessage from my form (not via the MQ) i.e below, this seems to work and the handler triggers passMessage() on my form.

```
myMQ.onMessage(Pass in a message);
```

BUT.. if I send a real message to the queue and wait for the onMessage() method in my MQ class to be triggered and receive the message, it does indeed receive the message but my eventhandler is not triggered.

Does anyone have any idea why this could be happening?

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at Events

Comment: Yup add your own event to MessageQueue class and rise it in onMessage handler. Then add event handler to your newly created event in form. Done :)

Comment: Oh, by the way where did you hind MessageListener class? I'am working with MQ right now and this would be very helpful for me.

Comment: I don't find a `MessageListener` in `System.Messaging`. What kind of API are you using?

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes I guess its IBM MQ.

Comment: Hi all - its an MQ platform we bought in, but it doesnt have much .NET compatibility. I've updated my code to show the EventHandler I've added as suggested (thank you for suggestion), but the event never seems to fire? Can anyone see what I've done wrong? How would I also pass the message text back to my form via teh handler? Thanks

Comment: Update: I tested my handler by calling onMessage() manually from my form and the handler triggers and notifies me that onMessage() has been called. But when a Message is received in the background and onMessage() is called (not by me) the event handler is not triggered? Does anyone have any idea as to what Im doing wrong? In a nutshell I would like to return the message received back to my form to display it to the user.

Answer (score 1):

To send a message to your form, you need to manage your message to be used in the thead of the form using `Invoke` method, other threads can not pass messages to the form.

i changed your code about how to do so:

```
public void passMessage(object s, EventArgs e)
{
   txtMessage.Invoke(delegate()
   {
      txtMessage.Text = "";
   });
}
```

Comment: Why should the message handling know about the form? I agree that this would provide OP with the ability to output the text on the form, but I think events would be a better option, no? Decoupling the act of displaying the message from the receiving of the message.

Comment: Hi there, thank you for this suggestion. I would prefer to pass the message back to my form via an eventhandler rather than the class knowing about my form. Thanks again.

Comment: really I'm asking for advice on the best way to pass the message received back to the form without the class having to directly know the form exists :)